# artifactory: automatically perform sha-256 checksum

Tags: artifactory

I've recently setup an instance of Artifactory (Pro) on a server and began deploying some artifacts for testing the instance. I noticed that any deployed artifact does not automatically calculate the SHA-256 checksum by default (I have to manually click on the link `Calculate` link). For example:

[image: example default checksum web element]

Is there a way to configure Artifactory to automatically perform the SHA-256 checksum for all artifacts that get deployed to the instance?

I cannot seem to find in JFrog's documentation or Artifactory's configuration page anything related to this capability; however, making this request since I assume I'm overlooking something.

Related: [RTFACT-6962](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6962), [RTFACT-12655](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-12655)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory 5.5 is planned to natively support SHA2 calculations (RTFACT-6962).
SHA2 will be calculated for every newly deployed artifact. For existing artifacts there will be an option to run the calculation as a background job.